# Show result of uploaded file validation to the user in Symfony3

Tags: jquery, symfony, file-upload, blueimp, oneupuploaderbundle

### INTRODUCTION

I am developing on `Windows 10 Pro` with `XAMPP` [1] which includes `PHP v7.0.9`.

- [1] [XAMPP for Windows](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)

I am using Symfony v3.1.5, [OneupUploaderBundle](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) and [Blueimp jQuery upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) in order to upload files to server.

While setting things up I followed documentation of `OneUpUploaderBundle` [2] and `jQuery file upload` [3], [4].

- [2] [OneupUploaderBundle documentation](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md)
- [3] [OneupUploaderBundle Blueimp example](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/frontend_blueimp.md)
- [4] [Blueimp jQuery file upload documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin)

### PROBLEM

I want to upload files to some directory and then check their [mime type](http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/File.html#method_getMimeType) and validate is file mime type allowed for uploading and after that - move them to custom directory (that can change from file to file), finally i want to persist file path and file name to database.

File upload works fine and files are uploaded to `oneup_uploader_endpoint('gallery')`. Even custom file `Namer` works and allows upload to custom directory.

Listeners are called, yet they are displayed in Symfony Profiler Events section `Not Called Listeners`. I suspect it might be so because of XMLHttpRequest (Ajax requests) that are performed by `Blueimp jQuery uploader` in order to upload files and display upload progress.

At the moment I use Javascript to filter allowed mime types. It helps, but it is not "trustworthy". For example if there is PDF file that has name `test.pdf.jpg` javascript will allow it based on extension in whitelist. But what if PDF file has name `test.jpg` - no one can be sure about real mimetype. So validation on server is needed. I am using mimetype filter on the server side as well.

**Problem is - if the files mimetype is not in the list - the file, simply, is not moved in target directory - technically it uploads fine as validation on server happens after full upload. (That is if I understand correctly. Please correct me if I am wrong about this.) And also I do not know how to get/show any message to user about upload being filtered by mimetype filter (white list).**

### QUESTION

So the question is: how to display feedback to user about file that is not put though white list after file is successfully uploaded by Blueimp jQuery uploader.

### CODE

my services.yml

```
services:
    app.ultra_helpers:
        class: AppBundle\UltraHelpers\UltraHelpers
        arguments: ['@service_container']

    app.upload_listener:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\UploadListener
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "@session", "@service_container"]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: oneup_uploader.pre_upload.gallery, method: onUpload }
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: oneup_uploader.post_upload.gallery, method: onPostUpload }

    app.alowed_mimetype_listener:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\AllowedMimetypeValidationListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: oneup_uploader.validation.gallery, method: onValidate }

    app.upload_unique_namer:
        class: AppBundle\Uploader\Naming\UploadUniqueNamer
        arguments: ["@session"]
```

my custom Namer

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Uploader\Naming;

use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Uploader\File\FileInterface;
use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Uploader\Naming\NamerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class UploadUniqueNamer implements NamerInterface
{
    private $session;

    public function __construct(Session $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a user directory name for the file being uploaded.
     *
     * @param FileInterface $file
     * @return string The directory name.
     */
    public function name(FileInterface $file)
    {
        $active_project_name = $this->session->get('active_project_name');
        $active_project_path = $this->session->get('active_project_path');
        $upload_files_path = $active_project_name . $active_project_path;
        $unique_name = uniqid();

        return sprintf('%s/%s_%s',
            $upload_files_path,
            $unique_name,
            $file->getClientOriginalName()
        );
    }
}
```

my config.yml

```
oneup_uploader:
    mappings:
        gallery:
            storage:
                type: flysystem
                filesystem: oneup_flysystem.gallery_filesystem

            frontend: blueimp
            enable_progress: true
            namer: app.upload_unique_namer

            allowed_mimetypes: [ image/png, image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/gif ]
            max_size: 10485760s

oneup_flysystem:
    adapters:
        my_adapter:
            local:
                directory: "%kernel.root_dir%/../data"

    filesystems:
        gallery:
            adapter: my_adapter
```

my upload listener:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Event\PreUploadEvent;
use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Event\PostUploadEvent;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container as Container;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use AppBundle\Entity\MyFile;

class UploadListener
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $entityManager;

    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    private $session;

    /**
     * @var Container
     */
    private $container;

    /**
     * @var originalName
     */
    protected $originalName;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager, Session $session, Container $container)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function onUpload(PreUploadEvent $event)
    {
        $file = $event->getFile();
        $this->originalName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    }

    public function onPostUpload(PostUploadEvent $event)
    {
        $ultra = $this->container->get('app.ultra_helpers');
        $file_path = $ultra->filterFileNameFromPath($event->getFile());

        $upload_files_path = $this->session->get('active_project_path');

        $my_file = new MyFile();
        $my_file->setName($upload_files_path);
        $my_file->setFile($file_path);
        $this->entityManager->persist($my_file);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
    }
}
```

my template that shows upload form `upload.html.twig`

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/blueimp/jquery.fileupload.css') }}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css') }}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap/bootstrap-theme.css') }}" />
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div id="box-list" class="clearfix">
        Go to: <a href="{{ path('file_list') }}">File list</a>
    </div>
    <div id="box-upload">
        <div id="box-file-upload">
            {{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'id': 'my-form-upload'}, 'method': 'POST'}) }}
                <div class="row form-message">
                    {{ form_errors(form) }}
                </div>
                <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                    <span>&nbsp;Choose files...</span>
                    {{ form_row(form.file, {'id': 'file-upload', 'attr': {'name': 'files[]', 'data-url': oneup_uploader_endpoint("gallery") }}) }}
                </span>
            {{ form_end(form) }}
        </div>
        <div id="box-progress">
            <div id="box-progress-bar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="box-info">
            <p>Upload status...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/blueimp/jquery.ui.widget.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/blueimp/jquery.iframe-transport.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/blueimp/jquery.fileupload.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function()
        {
            'use strict';
            $('#file-upload').on('click', function ()
            {
                $('#box-progress-bar').css('width', '1%');
            });

            $('#file-upload').on("fileuploadprocessfail", function(e, data)
            {
                var file = data.files[data.index];
                alert(file.error);
                console.log(file.error);
            });

            $('#file-upload').fileupload({
                dataType: 'json',
                add: function (e, data)
                {
                    var fileName = data.files[0].name;
                    var fileType = data.files[0].name.split('.').pop();
                    var allowedTypes = 'jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,png,PNG,gif,GIF,pdf,PDF';
                    if (allowedTypes.indexOf(fileType) < 0)
                    {
                        $('#box-progress-bar').css('width', '0');
                        $('<p/>').text(fileName).appendTo($('#box-info'));
                        $('<p class="wrong-file-type"/>').text('Invalid file type').appendTo($('#box-info'));
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('<p/>').text(fileName).appendTo($('#box-info'));
                        if ($('.button-upload').length == 0)
                        {
                            // disabling file input
                            $('input#file-upload').attr('disabled', true);

                            data.context = $('<button class="button-upload btn btn-primary start"/>').text('Upload')
                                    .appendTo($('#box-info'))
                                    .click(function ()
                                    {
                                        data.context = $('<p class="upload-success"/>').text('Uploading...').replaceAll($(this));
                                        ($('.button-cancel')).remove();
                                        data.submit();
                                    });
                            $('<button class="button-cancel btn btn-warning cancel" />').text('Cancel')
                                    .appendTo($('#box-info'))
                                    .click(function ()
                                    {
                                        $('#box-progress-bar').css('width', '0');
                                        //console.log('testing');
                                        var message = 'Upload canceled';
                                        ($('.button-upload')).remove();
                                        ($('.button-cancel')).remove();
                                        $('<p class="wrong-file-type"/>').text(message).appendTo($('#box-info'));
                                        // enabling file input
                                        $('input#file-upload').attr('disabled', false);
                                    });
                        }
                    }
                },
                progressall: function (e, data)
                {
                    var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                    $('#box-progress-bar').css('width', progress + '%');
                },
                done: function (e, data)
                {
                    data.context.text('Upload finished.');
                    // enabling file input
                    $('input#file-upload').attr('disabled', false);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Allowed mimetype listener

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Event\ValidationEvent;
use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Uploader\Exception\ValidationException;

class AllowedMimetypeValidationListener
{
    public function onValidate(ValidationEvent $event)
    {
        $config = $event->getConfig();
        $file   = $event->getFile();

        if (count($config['allowed_mimetypes']) == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        $mimetype = $file->getMimeType();

        if (!in_array($mimetype, $config['allowed_mimetypes']))
        {
            throw new ValidationException('error.whitelist');
        }
    }
}
```

### UPDATES

1. Added allowed mimetype listener code to the question

### CONCLUSION

Please advise.

Thank You for your time and knowledge.

Comment: Just setup response in your listener. `$event->getResponse()` and change it.

Comment: Or better throw exception from your listener.

Comment: I added listener code to the question at hand. And it looks like it should be throwing an exception, but it does not.

Comment: So the response code is "200" when you upload file with no white listed mime type?

Comment: Yes, I get response code "200" when uploading "PDF file". My mimetype whitelist is here `[ image/png, image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/gif ]`.

Comment: If I set allowed mimetypes as follows `[ image/png, image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/gif, application/pdf, application/x-pdf ]` PDF file that I upload is moved to target directory...

Comment: I figured it out - along with response "200" i get also `responseText` with following contents "{"files":[{"error":"error.whitelist"}]}" so it is possible to handle this error logic with javascript.